# Event after div has had class for X amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timer

I need to make a div2 visible after div1 has had a '.selected' class for X amount of seconds, and revert to hidden when div1 loses the '.selected' class.  What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can you control the code that sets and unsets the class?

Comment: You can add js logic on onLoad event of BODY

Comment: 1) if you're in control of adding/removing the class, do the extra logic in the same place. 2) if not, probably the only way is *polling*

Comment: no I can't directly control the code that unsets the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an class name event listener to an object to detect a change using this code:

```
function addClassNameListener(elemId, callback) {
var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
var lastClassName = elem.className;
window.setInterval( function() {   
   var className = elem.className;
    if (className !== lastClassName) {
        callback();   
        lastClassName = className;
    }
},10);
}
```

You can adapt that to look for a certain class name if you'd like :)

Here is it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/gJgmV/5/

**Edit**: This is probably a moderately intensive function as it is basically checking whether or not the class has changed every 10 millieconds.

If it is posible in your situation, perhaps it would be better to add a function to the onclick event of whatever sets the class. Heres a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/gJgmV/6/

Comment: this seems to be the best solution. But if this were used for, say 100 elements on one page, do you think this would cause some cpu choking? Or would it run efficiently enough?

Comment: Even with 100 elements, I dont think that the function will slow things down noticably. However I've editted my answer to include another solution if it does!

Comment: thanks! on a semi-side note, should i be able to see your code on that jsfiddle? or just the demo? because it doesn't show the code

Comment: You should be able to see the code on both of them. Can you not see the first one? I would suggest trying in another browser, I've had that problem before with jsFiddle

Comment: strange, I guess jsfiddle doesn't wanna show code in Chrome. well, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When the `.selected` class is added, you can put a timeout to show div 2:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //-- code to show div 2 here --//
}, 2000);
```

2000 is the time in milliseconds to wait before doing the function.

Then on the loss of `.selected` you can hide div2 again ( `hide()` );

Comment: or, add a `.delay(2000)` after the adding of the class and before the showing of div2. The delay can then be wiped with `.stop()`